# Not able to run custom java type in ParamConverter in JERSEY RS

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

I am new to JAXRS services. So for start i am writing a JAXRS application. In this application i'm writing custom java type through ParamConverterProvider and ParamConverter. I faced the following error when I click http://localhost:8080/advanced-jaxrs-01/webapi/date/12234003

Root Cause

> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
>   [[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public java.lang.String com.practise.mohit.MyCustomdate.getRequestedDate(com.practise.mohit.MyDate) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=GET, consumedTypes=[], producedTypes=[text/plain], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=MethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.practise.mohit.MyCustomdate, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@18e98015]}, handlingMethod=public java.lang.String com.practise.mohit.MyCustomdate.getRequestedDate(com.practise.mohit.MyDate), parameters=[Parameter [type=class com.practise.mohit.MyDate, source=dateString, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class java.lang.String}, nameBindings=[]}']
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:410)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:157)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:280)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:277)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:262)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
>       javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>       org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>       org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>       org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>       org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>       org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

My pom.xml

```
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <!--   <scope>provided</scope> -->
</dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
</dependency>

   </dependencies>
```

My ParamConverterProvider

```
@Provider
public class MyParamConverterProvider implements ParamConverterProvider{
    @Override
    public <T> ParamConverter<T> getConverter(Class<T> rawType, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations) {
        if(rawType.equals(DateResource.class)){
           // return (ParamConverter<T>) new MyDate();
            return (ParamConverter<T>) new DateResource();
            //return (ParamConverter<T>) new ParamConverter<DateResource>();
        }
        return null;
    }

    }
```

My ParamConverter

```
public class DateResource implements ParamConverter<MyDate> {
@Override
    public MyDate fromString(String value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (value == null || value.trim().isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }

         MyDate dateParamModel = new MyDate();
        dateParamModel.setDateAsString(value);
        return  dateParamModel;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString(MyDate mo) {


            return ((MyDate) mo).getDateAsString();
    }

}
```

My Custom Java type class

```
public class MyDate {


    private String dateAsString;

    public String getDateAsString() {
        return dateAsString;
    }

    public void setDateAsString(String dateAsString) {
        this.dateAsString = dateAsString;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDate() {
        LocalDateTime dateTime = null;
        try {
            dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateAsString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
            System.err.println("Conversion of dateAsString: " + dateAsString + " using ISO date time failed.");
        }
        try {
            dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateAsString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
            System.err.println("Conversion of dateAsString: " + dateAsString + " using ISO date failed.");
        }

        return dateTime;
    }
}
```

And finally my Resource

```
@Path("date/{dateString}")
public class MyCustomdate {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    //public String getRequestedDate(@PathParam("dateString") String dateString)
    public String getRequestedDate(@PathParam("dateString") MyDate myDate)
    {
        return "Got"+ myDate.getDate() ;
    }

}
```

And My main class

```
@ApplicationPath("webapi")
public class MyRestApiApp extends Application {

}
```

Please guide on this issue.

Comment: have you tried registering `MyParamConverterProvider` in the constructor of `MyRestApiApp` like `register(MyParamConverterProvider.class)`?

Comment: @JanGassen yes i did now...but after this i'm having error A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in com.practise.mohit.MyRestApiApp class   .... this means it is trying to instantiate my converter DateResource, which is not allowed..can you guide me on this now

Comment: Does your class `MyRestApiApp` have a default-constructor with no arguments? And the the register call inside of it?

Comment: @JanGassen  yes, i declared it like....... MyRestApiApp() {
 ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig();
 
 rc.register(MyParamConverterProvider.class);
 }

Comment: can you derive `MyRestApiApp` from `ResourceConfig` (which is a subclass of `Application`) and then just call `register` in the constructor? And can you maybe clarify which constructor couldn't be found? `MyRestApiApp` or `DateResource `?

Comment: @JanGassen aplogies for delayed response,  i updated the main to MyRestApiApp() {
     register(MyParamConverterProvider.class);
    
     packages("com.practise.mohit");
 } but still it Could not find a suitable constructor in com.practise.mohit.MyRestApiApp class.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(rawType.equals(DateResource.class)){
```

This is wrong. You need to be checking for the *parameter type*. What Jersey will do when validating the resources parameters is check all the `ParamConverterProvider`s to see if they all return something other then null for that parameter type. Since you are checking the converter type instead of the parameter type, it returns null during the check for the `MyDate` parameter. That's when the `ModelValidationExeption` occurs.

Just change it to check for the parameter type you want to convert.

```
if(rawType.equals(MyDate.class)){
```

---

Also remove `jaxrs-ri` from your dependencies. You don't need it.

Comment: i changed MyParamConverterProvider according to if(rawType.equals(MyDate.class)) but the same error persists which is  java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in com.practise.mohit.MyRestApiApp class.

Comment: How is it the same error? The original error was ModelValidationException. That error doesn't make any sense with the code you are showing. Can you post the whole stack trace?

Comment: i have updated the trace in above post, can you have on that now

Comment: Please don't invalidate answers by changing your original post. If you want to make an update to your post, then put a note at the bottom of it that you have an update, and post your new content below that.

Comment: Understood, i will do so, and back to the issue, do you have any idea on this, i already mug up my mind on this, still issue persists

Comment: No, it's not something I can reproduce. Is that all that's in your `MyRestApiApp` class?

Comment: yes it is, i'm extending resoruceConfig class and using no-arg constructor, MyRestApiApp() {
 register(MyParamConverterProvider.class);
     packages("com.practise.mohit");
 } and according to error it is not able to find default constructor in this main class